# iText 5.5.3 ColumnText doesn't wrap text correctly due to the way font size is measured

Tags: java, itext

### Question Setup

I am trying to accurately determine the width of a font (Ubuntu Italic), though iText appears to ignore the portion of the last glyph after the horizontal advance as shown in the image below.

[image: ff using Ubuntu Italic Font]

The code I used to generate this example is as follows:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.pdf"));
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);

document.open();

String text = "ff";
Chunk chunk = new Chunk(text, FontFactory.getFont("Ubuntu-Italic.ttf", 72)
Phrase phrase = new Phrase(chunk);

float width = ColumnText.getWidth(phrase);
System.out.println(width + ", " + chunk.getWidthPoint());

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
table.setTotalWidth(width);

PdfPCell cell = table.getDefaultCell();
cell.setPadding(0);
cell.setUseDescender(true);
cell.setUseAscender(true);
table.addCell(phrase);

float height = table.calculateHeights();

PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();

ColumnText columnText = new ColumnText(canvas);
columnText.setSimpleColumn(36, 756 - height, 36 + width, 756);
columnText.addElement(table);
columnText.go();

document.close();
out.close();
```

As demonstrated in the code I tried both `ColumnText.getWidth(phrase)` as well as `chunk.getWidthPoint()` which both return the same value, with a little bit of floating point difference.

### Question

The code I wrote above simulates a situation in iText where text doesn't wrap correctly to the next line.  The problem I'm having is that ColumnText, in the code I am using, is cropped.  The issue is that because of the way iText measures text, the ColumnText thinks there is enough room for the `f` at the right edge when in fact there really isn't, so in my situation it is getting cut off.  Is there a way to force ColumnText to measure the width of the font differently so that this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by adding padding on the left and right side of the `PdfPCell` and by increasing the width of the `ColumnText` equal to the padding I added. That way the text flows the same way and allows for the fact that iText only takes into account the horizontal advance values of the font.

Comment: *adding padding on the right side* - if you look at the definition of the letter `f` in my answer, you'll see that you should **add some padding on the *left* side, too.** You can also see the cut-off in your test PDF if you zoom in.

Answer (score 1):

Your observation

> The right border that cuts through the `f`

corresponds with the definition of the Ubuntu-Italic letter f:

[image: Ubuntu-Italic letter f]

The width you get is the width of the letter on the base line, the horizontal advance, it is **not** the distance from the left-most to the right-most x coordinate.

Comment: I appreciate the picture and the clarification though my question isn't so much about the font but how to make iText respect the distance from the left-most to the right-most x coordinate.  I updated the title as well as organized the question to make this more clear.

Comment: IText *does not know* the distance from the left-most to the right-most x coordinate. All it knows is the horizontal displacement. For more it would have to analyze font data in detail which is not its focus. For that you should additionally employ a font-centric library.

Comment: Using a font-centric library doesn't help my situation since ColumnText controls the flow of the text.

Comment: I am afraid it is as I said, iText only knows the horizontal advance values.